# Powershell - Piping information into an object

Tags: excel, powershell

How would I pipe the information I've pulled out from a spreadsheet into a Powershell object?

```
$rangeAddr=$startCell + ":" + $endCell
    $sh.Range($rangeAddr).Value2 | foreach {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{"Build"=$sh.Name;"AppName"=$_;}
    }
```

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using and what isn't working as you expect with the script you posted. BTW the double quotes around `"Build"` and `"AppName"` are not necessary and neither is that last semi-colon.

Comment: I'm using 1.0 on an enterprise machine (can't upgrade) - I'm trying to create an object from the data I'm pulling out of an Excel spreadsheet

Comment: Are you getting error or not the results you expected?  I assume for Build you really want the Name of the worksheet?  And for AppName, you want the cell contents?

Comment: Yes, I'm not getting any errors at the moment. Ideally I would like to create one object with four properties? How feasible is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612072/powershell-pulling-information-from-an-extra-column - the full code is there - but I want to pull down information from column J and K as well, then pipe it all into an object to export to a CSV file under 4 different columns

Comment: I'm not sure how you wouldn't be getting errors as there is *no* `-Property` parameter on New-Object in PowerShell 1.0.

Comment: Got some help here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211632/read-excel-sheet-in-powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe creating objects from hash tables was in V2, but not V1.

Does this work?

```
$rangeAddr=$startCell + ":" + $endCell
    $sh.Range($rangeAddr).Value2 |
      foreach {
        $NewObject = "" | Select Build,Name
        $Newobject.Build    = $sh.Name
        $NewObject.Name  = $_ 
        $NewObject
       }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works great. Is it possible to add a third/fourth column with information from column J/K in the spreadsheet (same start/endcell)?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but I don't use com enough to tell you off the top of my head.

Comment: I think you have an issue between your use of `Select Build,*Name*` and the later use of `$NewObject.*AppName*`.  Those should be the same. :-)