# Search for a file from a list

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I need to read a column in Excel file and search for that file in shared directory.

Example:

`File.csv`:

```
10099
20099
93099
```

You have to search for file name with `10099` and so on and need the path of the file as output.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please show us what you've tried and explain how the actual results were different from what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

for read column excell via powershell read this links
[link1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx)
[linke2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211632/read-excel-sheet-in-powershell)
this simple script for find particular name in all partitions

```
$name = Read-Host "which name you want find"
 Get-PSDrive | where { $_.Provider -match "FileSystem"} | select Root | foreach { Get-ChildItem $_.Root -Recurse -Name $name -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' }
```

You can change script if you want don't ask user for file name

Comment: Is there a any way i can do it for more than 1000 file names through a batch ??

Comment: do you want 1000 file name find just in once script run ?check this `"name1","name2","name3" | foreach { get-childitem -filter $_}`

Comment: Yeah , may be i can put it in a text file and the script will read it and give the path of files

Comment: as i tell you with foreach can send all strings for search