# PowerShell saving excel sheet in unreadable format

Tags: excel, powershell

I have the below piece of code that checks for Files to Tapes jobs for a database and gives the output in an excel sheet.

```
$date = Get-Date
$day = $date.Day
$hour = $date.Hour 
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$Sheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item(1)
#Counter variable for rows and columns
$intRow = 1
$intCol = 1

$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,1) = "Tasks/Servers"     
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,2) = "DateLastRun"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,3) = "PRX1CSDB01"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,4) = "PRX1CSDB02"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,5) = "PRX1CSDB03"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,6) = "PRX1CSDB11"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,7) = "PRX1CSDB12"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow,8) = "PRX1CSDB13"
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow+1,1) = "File To Tape weekly Full Backup"
$Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Item(1).Borders.LineStyle = 1

#FTT.txt contains the path for a list of servers
$path =  Get-Content D:\Raghav\DB_Integrated\FTT.txt

foreach ($server in $path)
{
If (Test-Path $server)
{
$BckpWeek = gci -path $server | select-object | where {$_.Name -like "*logw*"} | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow+1,$intCol+1) = $BckpWeek.LastWriteTime.ToString('MMddyyyy')
$Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Item($intRow).Borders.LineStyle = 1
$x = (get-date) - ([datetime]$BckpWeek.LastWriteTime)
if( $x.days -gt 7){$status_week = "Failed"}
else{$status_week = "Successful"}
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow+1,$intCol+2) = $status_week
$intCol++
}
else
{
$Sheet.Cells.Item($intRow+1,$intCol+2) = "Path Not Found"
$intCol++
}
}
$Sheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
$workBook.SaveAs("C:\Users\Output.xlsx",51)
$excel.Quit()
```

However, when I try to import the contents of `Output.xlsx` into a variable say `$cc`, I get data in an unreadable format.

```
$cc = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Output.xlsx"
```

Attached is the image for what I get on exporting output.xlsx into $cc. I tried to put the output in csv format too. But that also doesnt seem to help.[image: output file]Anybody having any idea on this or having faced any similar situation before?

Comment: Hi, why use `Import-CSV`? `xslx` is different from `CSV`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to PowerShell. Is there any way by which we can import the contents of an xlsx file to a variable in powershell?

Comment: Sure, here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211632/read-excel-sheet-in-powershell)

Comment: You might also want to consider using the ADO.NET [`OleDbConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: If you'd like to avoid doing all that work in .NET classes you can also use the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/2.2.9) which is easier to work with and doesn't require Excel to be present on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ZevSpitz - Looking for the OleDbConnection class, I landed up at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pstips/2014/06/02/get-excel-data-without-excel/ . This is what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me out in the right direction.

@MikeGaruccio - Unfortunately, I didn't find Import-Excel command in Get-Help menu. I am using Powershell 4.0. Anyways, thank you for the suggestion.