# Scheduled script adding to new cells in xlsx

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying replicate an end users experience by monitoring the time it takes to copy a large file off of a network directory.

I'm using `Measure-Command` to find the total time it takes to copy an item from a network directory onto the computer that this script is scheduled on (using Windows Scheduler) and output the time in an xlsx.

The issue I'm running into is that every time this script runs off of the scheduler (daily), it overwrites the previous day's data instead of posting the result in the next cell. When I run it manually multiple times, it works just fine and posts separate results under each other. I think the issue is that it's going by the instance (so running the code a handful of  times in the same PowerShell instance sees that the `$previousRow` works, but in the daily schedule it opens a new instance every time and writes over the old data in cell (1,1) and (1,2).

Any suggestions on how to keep historical data?

```
$seconds = Measure-Command {
    Copy-Item -Path X:\shareddrive\test.pdf -Destination C:\Users\Me\Desktop
} | select TotalSeconds

$erroractionpreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$a = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$dt = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
$a.Workbooks.Open("X:\shareddrive\output\timesample.xlsx")
$a.Visible = $true
$a.Worksheets.Item(1)

$previousRow += 1
$a.Cells.Item($previousRow,1) = "OfficeLocation - " + $dt
$a.Cells.Item($previousRow,2) =  $seconds.TotalSeconds

$a.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
$a.Workbooks.Close()
$a.Quit()
Remove-Item -Path C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you haven't copied all your code in? But it looks like you aren't actually defining `$previousRow` anywhere? So your existing code runs `$previousRow += 1` and that sets `$previousRow` to 1... which means each time the code runs it will hit row 1 first

To be able to find the row that has the last information in it (ie the value to set $previousValue to + 1) you can use this code:

```
$filepath = "C:\Folder\ExcelFile.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $False
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($filepath)
$WorkSheet = $objExcel.WorkSheets.item(1)
$WorkSheet.activate()

[int]$lastRowvalue = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1) - 1
$lastrow = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($lastRowvalue, 1).Value2
write-host $previousValue 
write-host $lastRowvalue
```

Copy/paste from here (with a few slight modifications): [To get the value of last cell used in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572211/to-get-the-value-of-last-cell-used-in-excel)

That tells you the last row with data... so you would need to add 1 to that first before you set it as the value for $previousRow:

```
$previousRow = $previousRow + 1
```

Comment: oh I see, hmmm! that makes sense, but I'm not entirely should what I should set `$previousRow` equal to in order to take the row beforehand. When I run this script manually multiple times, it pushes down to the next row so it goes from row 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc. Do you have any suggestions on what to change?