# How to read an Excel file in PowerShell on Linux?

Tags: excel, linux, powershell, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

As many of you are aware, PowerShell can now be [installed and used on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2) and it has worked surprisingly well for me so far. However, I wonder if the content of an Excel file can be read given that Excel cannot be installed on Linux. What I have found online is that the PS script to open an Excel file is:

```
# Script copied and pasted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48443536/how-to-read-excel-files-in-powershell

$excel = New-Object -com excel.application
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open("c:\users\administrator\my_test.xls")
```

But I get the error:

```
New-Object: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'com'.
```

When I remove the parameter and run the script, this is the error I get:

```
New-Object: Cannot find type [excel.application]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Since I'm on Linux (ubuntu 22.04), I can use `xls2csv` on bash to convert the Excel file to csv and then use `Get-Content` on PowerShell. But I would like to know if there is a way to do it on PowerShell since I am currently learning it.

Thank you.

Comment: How about using the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am grateful to @Olaf who pointed out the [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.8.1) module from Doug Finke.

After installing the module with:

```
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel
```

importing the file is as easy as:

```
$data = Import-Excel c:\users\administrator\my_test.xls
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you

Comment: @DougFinke It sure did! Thank you for an awesome, easy-to-use module.