# How to import keys from an Excel file to Azure key vault

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I want to add/update around 50 keys to my key vault in Azure. Is there a way to add/update these keys using an Excel file and then deploy it through powershell script?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Yes".

1. Read Excel using Powershell: [Read Excel sheet in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211632/read-excel-sheet-in-powershell)
2. Import Keys using Powershell: [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-azure-key-vault-using-azure-powershell/#:~:text=You%20can%20create%20or%20import%20key%20%28s%29%20in,key%20in%20software%20in%20the%20Key%20Vault%20service](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-azure-key-vault-using-azure-powershell/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20or%20import%20key%20%28s%29%20in,key%20in%20software%20in%20the%20Key%20Vault%20service).